# Like button on online advertisements

Tags: facebook-like, ads

Whenever I go to create the code for the like box/button to place on our website/advertisements I get an error message. Is this a fb issue or operator error issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate a like button just fine and it functioned perfectly. Make sure you're using their social plugin service at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Also if your website doesn't have XFBML enabled make sure you un-check the `Send Button` option.

Answer (score 0):

A Like plugin should be able to be used with any valid URL. 
It may be misconfigured if it's not working for you.

However, regardless of any technical issues you're having, this is expressly against Facebook policy (see https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ )

```
IV.4.a Your advertisements must not include or be paired with any Platform
integrations, including social plugins such as the Like button,
without our written permission.
```

and

```
IV.4.e Ad networks, ad exchanges, and data brokers must not use Facebook’s Platform,
logos, and trademarks (including, but not limited to, Platform APIs, social 
plugins, the Share button, and the F logo).
```